# Create TINYINT column type in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mariadb

I want to create TINYINT column type using JPA for MariaDB

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
public class Terminals implements Serializable {

   @Column
   private Boolean enabled;
   ....
}
```

But this creates BIT column type. Is there any way to implement it?

Comment: A simple search found the answer:  https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-smallint-tinyint-int-column-to-boolean

Comment: I found similar solution with @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType") But it's not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition--

Answer (score 2):

```
@Type(type = "numeric_boolean")
@Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT")
private Boolean enabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TINYINT")

private int enabled;
```

you can use this

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?